# How can I delete the world file in a minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I'm attempting to create a plugin but the plugin I'm making uses its own world gen system so I need to delete the world file but everytime I do that the file recreates does anyone know how I can stop this from happening?

Comment: First stop your server, then go to your server files and delete the folder with the name "world" and then put whatever plugin you want in the plugins folder and then restart the server, and anyways, which type of plugin you are using? Depending on it I might be able to give another answer.

Comment: @RyugaGod Please don't answer questions in comments

Comment: @RyugaGod You can always edit an answer! As [at]pppery said, I would make that an answer. It helps people who come to this question wondering the same thing.

Comment: @Potterton ok, I created an answer

Answer (score 2):

First stop your server, then go to your server files and delete the folder with the name "world" and then put whatever plugin you want in the plugins folder and then restart the server. It should work in that way, and also when you start the server, the server will automatically generate a world. I don't know much about plugins, but if your plugin uses a world gen system (something like mutiworld) then it will need a world to start with. A server cannot be started without a world create and you will not be able to use the in game plugin commands without the server started.

I hope this helped, if not then sorry.

Comment: sorry for the late response but thanks for the help I'll see if this works!